# How to Clean Dynamic URL's with .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have tried the following in htaccess but does not seem to work,

```
Options +FollowSymLinks +Indexes +MultiViews

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ $1.php?bid=$2&page=$3 [L]
```

By doing this,

```
http://www.turkish-property-world.com/antalya_apartment.php?bid=4&page=1
```

should be

```
http://www.turkish-property-world.com/antalya_apartment/4/1
```

Comment: Try replacing the last rule with `RewriteRule ^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ $1.php?bid=$2&page=$3 [L]`

Comment: thanks for reply. i have just replaced with above rule, still not changing.

Comment: Maybe addind `RewriteEngine On` at the start ?

Comment: above is what i have in htaccess

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/$ $1.php?bid=$2&page=$3 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ $1.php?bid=$2&page=$3 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: i have stripped out everything in htacces and just added the following 4 lines, still the same.

Comment: I've edited my post, this have worked for me, but maybe you've tried with last slash, please retry with this script, it will work

Comment: when you request by this, http://www.turkish-property-world.com/antalya_apartment/4/1 what you receive ? 404 ?

Comment: no there is no 404 for above link, it opens with no style.css or images. when i click the next page (pagination i get a link like this http://www.turkish-property-world.com/antalya_apartment/4/1?bid=4&page=2

Comment: so your htaccess works, you have to do some changes in your code

Answer (score 1):

Your rule is correct but real problem is your use of `MultiViews`. Take it out using:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks +Indexes -MultiViews

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ $1.php?bid=$2&page=$3 [L,QSA]
```

- Option `MultiViews` is used by `Apache's content negotiation module` that runs before `mod_rewrite` and and makes Apache server match extensions of files. So `/file` can be in URL but it will serve `/file.php`.

Comment: i have added the follow only, in htaccess for some reason still no change.